# single-character user input and fgets

Tags: c, validation, user-input, fgets

Noob question here, but I am teaching myself C and trying to figure out user input in the safe, correct way (for reference this is the morse code array exercise in the GNU C Programming Tutorial at 10.6 (58-59) and 15.5.5 (107)).

My desired program flow is:

- prompt user for a single numeral
- get user input
- validate user input
- if valid print correct array item

The problem is that if the user simply enters a hard return, the array reading function reads and prints from my_array[0]. I can't figure out how to cause a return to fail the validation.

in main:

```
if (get_line (digit_input, sizeof (digit_input), stdin) != NULL ) {
  if (validate (digit_input) == 0) {
    digit = atoi (digit_input);
    printf("\nThe Morse code for %d is: ", digit);
    morse(digit);
}
```

get_line and validate functions:

```
char *get_line(char *s, size_t n, FILE *f) {
  unsigned int last;
  char *p = fgets (s, n, f);

  if (p != NULL) {
    last = (strlen(s) - 1);
    if (s[last] == '\n') s[last] = '\0';
  }
  return p;
}
```

---

```
int validate(char *a) { 
  unsigned x;

  for (x = 0; x < strlen(a); x++)
    if ( !isdigit(a[x]) || (a[1] != '\0' )) return -1;

  return 0;
}
```

How I can invalidate blank input? (i.e, if the string reads \n\0?) And why is a no-character (i.e., \n) input made into a 0 and passed to the array reading function?

Thanks everybody for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following test in the beggining of `validate` function:

```
if (strlen(a) == 0) return -1;
```

So, blank input will be invalidated.

Comment: Thanks--I ended up using this line since it seems the most generic. Set a different return value from the non-numeral entry since i figured a blank entry is a different problem from a wrong input type.

Comment: "strlen(a)==0" is an overkill (and in some scenarios could degrade performance). "a[0]=='\0'" is much faster - why go all the way to the string's end, just to know if it's empty?

Comment: @ ugoren point taken. i realize now that validate relies on get_line which I've read is bad form for anything but main() but one step at a time, etc. Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

Your `validate` function will return 0 if `strlen()` is 0, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do I properly understand that you expect exactly one digit to be entered?

Just explicitly check that the length of the string is exactly 1 and the char is a digit:

```
int validate(char *a) { 
  return strlen(a)==1 && isdigit(a[0]) ? 0 : -1
}
```